# setting td's width isn't working in this table

Tags: html, css

This is my html code:

```
      <table cellspacing="0" id="ext_invited_table">
                <tbody id="ext_invited_table_body">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="internal_case">
                        </td>
                        <td class="attendee_id" style="display:none;">0</td>
                        <td >Non</td>
                        <td style="display:none;">add_ext_invited_tableadd_ext_invited_tableadd_ext_invited_tableadd_ext_invited_table</td>
                        <td style="display:none;">add_ext_invited_tableadd_ext_invited_tableadd_ext_invited_table</td>
                        <td>add_ext_invited_tableadd_ext_invited_tableadd_ext_invited_table, add_ext_invited_tableadd_ext_invited_tableadd_ext_invited_tableadd_ext_invited_table</td><td>a@a.com</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="button" id="invited_delete_btn">
                        </td>
                        <td style="display:none;">Asia/Tehran</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

This is my css:

```
td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L2qEx/)

In here, I want to set the td's width, but it is not working.

Can I ask what is the problem please?

Comment: `add_ext_invited_tableadd_ext_invited_tableadd_ext_invited_table, add_ext_invited_tableadd_ext_invited_tableadd_ext_invited_tableadd_ext_invited_table` is not being wrapped, so it will stop the correct `width` from working properly.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to set width in here? except delete style: none???

Comment: The `width` is being ignored, because you're not wrapping the text, so it just expands to however long the text is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want every `<td>` to have the same width, then you'll need to add some CSS to break the long word up:

```
word-break:break-all;
```

You might want to add

```
vertical-align:top
```

As well, to align the text to the top of the `<td>`

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2qEx/6/)

Comment: THANKS! for the fast response :). I'll select after 6min

Answer (score 0):

```
td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px; /* Prevents Text from expanding the td */
    overflow: hidden; /* Hides the extra stuff after the end of the td */
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove style=display:none of yours td in html document.
the Css look for page first.